# Using a nondependent nested class of a parent template class as a member in a child class

Tags: c++, templates, nested-class

I was looking through the C++ templates section on the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq) and have come across this example (of code that doesn't compile) regarding [using nondependent nested classes of a parent template class as members in a child class](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/nondependent-name-lookup-types.html):

```
template<typename T>
class B {
public:
  class Xyz { ... };  ← type nested in class B<T>
  typedef int Pqr;    ← type nested in class B<T>
};

template<typename T>
class D : public B<T> {
public:
  void g()
  {
    Xyz x;  ← bad (even though some compilers erroneously (temporarily?) accept it)
    Pqr y;  ← bad (even though some compilers erroneously (temporarily?) accept it)
  }
};
```

### C++ FAQ 35.18

> Unfortunately this doesn't work either because those names (are you
>   ready? are you sitting down?) are not necessarily types. "Huh?!?" you
>   say. "Not types?!?" you exclaim. "That's crazy; any fool can SEE they
>   are types; just look!!!" you protest. Sorry, the fact is that they
>   might not be types. The reason is that there can be a specialization
>   of B, say B, where B::Xyz is a data member, for example.
>   Because of this potential specialization, the compiler cannot assume
>   that B::Xyz is a type until it knows T. The solution is to give the
>   compiler a hint via the typename keyword:

So the author states that **`there can be a specialization of B<T>, say B<Foo>, where B<Foo>::Xyz is a data member, for example.`**. This is the part I don't really understand - how could specializing a template class (without inheriting from it) **add** another member to the class, that, in another specialization (e.g. `B<Baz>`) wouldn't exist? This is, of course, assuming stuff like *D's static if* don't exist.

Am I missing something?

Comment: The tag C++-faq isn't related to the website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you explicitly specialize a class template, you are fully redefining the class for the given template arguments. Here's a simple example:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo
{
  typedef T type;
};

template <>
struct foo<int>
{
  static int type;
};
```

Now, if I instantiate a `foo` with any other template argument than `int`, the member `type` is a type. Otherwise, it is an `int` data member.

Comment: Good one, I hadn't thought of that!